# How can I make a timer to exit my program

Tags: c#, timer, xna, boolean, exit

I need to make a timer that will exit my program after 3 seconds - when a Bool is set to true - how can I do so?
I have tried using a few basic timers in a new class, but this doesn't seem to work.
I used the timer here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx but it isn't working.

```
private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

public static void Main()
{
    // Create a timer with a ten second interval.
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

    // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
    aTimer.Interval = 2000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;

}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Game1.timedOrNo = true
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried and did not work?

Comment: As was already mentioned earlier, _post your code_.  The link you added is like tits on a bull; useless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class issues in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503340/class-issues-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Instead of asking new question, improve your previous question.

Comment: I have edited my question and posted my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use XNA (from the tag list) you should have a following method in your `Game` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
/// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
}
```

So you need to check if 3 seconds elapsed, and then exit:

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
/// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds >= 3)
        this.Exit;
}
```

Comment: it isn't working for me. `if(bool232 == true)
                if (gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds >= 3)
                {
                    this.Exit();
                }`

Comment: @user3088260 add the code of your `Game1` class, so we can make sure you do everything correctly. I would also get rid of `if(bool232 == true)`. The way I wrote this should be just ok.

Comment: I cant get rid of `if(bool232 == true)` because I want the timer to start when the boolean is true

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually have `aTimer.Start();` somewhere in your code, with what you posted the timer will indeed trigger the `OnTimedEvent` after two seconds and set your `bool` to `true`. All you need to do now is check the state of the `bool` somewhere, preferably in the `Update` method of `Game1` with the [`Exit` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203874.aspx) like this :

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (timedOrNo)
    {
        Exit();
    }
}
```

As an alternative, since you can only exit once, the boolean is not really needed and you can close the application directly when the timer triggers :

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Game1.Exit();
}
```

---

As a side note, you should initiate the Interval directly in the constructor with `new System.Timers.Timer(2000);` instead of setting it to 10 seconds and then immediately to 2 manually. Also, you should change the `2000` to `3000` if you want it to exit after three seconds like you initially asked.